# Grep to find item in Perl array

Tags: perl, grep

Every time I input something the code always tells me that it exists. But I know some of the inputs do not exist. What is wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@array = <>;
print "Enter the word you what to match\n";
chomp($match = <STDIN>);

if (grep($match, @array)) {
    print "found it\n";
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The first arg that you give to grep needs to evaluate as true or false to indicate whether there was a match. So it should be:

```
# note that grep returns a list, so $matched needs to be in brackets to get the 
# actual value, otherwise $matched will just contain the number of matches
if (my ($matched) = grep $_ eq $match, @array) {
    print "found it: $matched\n";
}
```

If you need to match on a lot of different values, it might also be worth for you to consider putting the `array` data into a `hash`, since hashes allow you to do this efficiently without having to iterate through the list.

```
# convert array to a hash with the array elements as the hash keys and the values are simply 1
my %hash = map {$_ => 1} @array;

# check if the hash contains $match
if (defined $hash{$match}) {
    print "found it\n";
}
```

Answer (score 34):

You seem to be using `grep()` like the Unix `grep` utility, which is wrong.

Perl's [`grep()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) in scalar context evaluates the expression for each element of a list and returns the number of times the expression was true.
So when `$match` contains any "true" value, `grep($match, @array)` in scalar context will always return the number of elements in `@array`.

Instead, try using the pattern matching operator:

```
if (grep /$match/, @array) {
    print "found it\n";
}
```

Comment: Without the anchors on the pattern, i.e. `(grep /^$match$/, @array)`, searching for `$match = 1` in an array of `(12)` will return true when you'd probably expect false, because `1` happens to be a substring of `12`

Answer (score 3):

This could be done using [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil#first-BLOCK-LIST)'s `first` function:

```
use List::Util qw/first/;

my @array = qw/foo bar baz/;
print first { $_ eq 'bar' } @array;
```

Other functions from `List::Util` like `max`, `min`, `sum` also may be useful for you

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what eugene and stevenl posted, you might encounter problems with using both `<>` and `<STDIN>` in one script: `<>` iterates through (=concatenating) all files given as command line arguments.

However, should a user ever forget to specify a file on the command line, it will read from STDIN, and your code will wait forever on input

Answer (score 1):

I could happen that if your array contains the string "hello", and if you are searching for "he", grep returns true, although, "he" may not be an array element.

Perhaps,

`if (grep(/^$match$/, @array))` more apt.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check single value in multiple arrays like,

```
if (grep /$match/, @array, @array_one, @array_two, @array_Three)
{
    print "found it\n";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending your answer a little bit more to explain how it solves the problem.