# Perl: Searching for item in an Array

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, hash, perl-data-structures

Given an `array @A` we want to check if the `element $B` is in it. One way is to say this:

```
Foreach $element (@A){
    if($element eq $B){
        print "$B is in array A";
    }
}
```

However when it gets to Perl, I am thinking always about the most elegant way. And this is what I am thinking:
Is there a way to find out if array A contains B if we convert A to a variable string and use

```
index(@A,$B)=>0
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898499/grep-to-find-item-in-perl-array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086874/find-the-item-in-an-array-that-meets-a-specific-criteria-if-there-is-one-perl

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are *many ways* to find out whether the element is present in the array or not:

1. **Using foreach**

   ```
   foreach my $element (@a) {
       if($element eq $b) {
          # do something             
          last;
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Using Grep:**

   ```
   my $found = grep { $_ eq $b } @a;
   ```
3. **Using [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil) module**

   ```
   use List::Util qw(first); 

   my $found = first { $_ eq $b } @a;
   ```
4. **Using Hash initialised by a Slice**

   ```
   my %check;
   @check{@a} = ();

   my $found = exists $check{$b};
   ```
5. **Using Hash initialised by map**

   ```
   my %check = map { $_ => 1 } @a;

   my $found = $check{$b};
   ```

Comment: The List::Util::first() example is (potentially) subtly incorrect when searching for false values, since `$found` will also evaluate false.  (`die unless $found` ... oops!)  [List::MoreUtils::any](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils) does the right thing here.

Answer (score 6):

```
use 5.10.1;

$B ~~ @A and say '$B in @A';
```

Comment: You have to be very careful with this because this distributes the match over the elements. If @A has an array reference element that contains $B, this will still match even though $B isn't a top level element of @A. The smart match is fundamentally broken for this and many other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
use List::AllUtils qw/ any /;
print "\@A contains $B" if any { $B eq $_ } @A;
```

Comment: I would recommend `first` in this case, as it does not have to traverse whole array. It can stop when item is found.

Comment: any can stop too because it needs only one element to be true.

Comment: Beware that `first` can also return a false value if it finds, e.g., "0", which would confound the example given in this answer.  `any` has the desired semantics.